# How do I hide login view after a condition?

Tags: asp.net-core, model-view-controller, authorization, asp.net-identity

I want to restrict a view after a user login into system.

Example: I have a register view. After a user login into system I want to block access to register view. Because we don't need to view this view. How can I do that?

Comment: hey, removed the accessibility tag as that is related to making products accessible for people with disabilities etc. Hope you get your answer!

Comment: In your controller action check if a user is logged in, if so redirect the user to another page.

Comment: I use [AllowAnonymous] attribute when i allow to users the Login view or Register view. How can i restrict them when user is login?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need store the login infomation in session or cookie, then you can get it. In your register page method, you can read the login info and decide which page to choose.

```
public IActionResult registerView(){
    // you can set login info in session or another better ways
    var isLogin=HttpContext.Session.GetString("isLogin");
    if(isLogin==null || isLogin==""){
        return View();
    }else{
        return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
    }
}
```